# XMLStarlet does not remove attributes

Tags: xml, bash, xml-namespaces, xmlstarlet

I want to keep `xmlns:md` and remove all the other attributes from the xml. However, xmlstarlet failed to remove the attributes.

```bash
xmlstarlet ed -d '/md:EntityDescriptor/@xmlns' <<< '<md:EntityDescriptor xmlns="urn:_" xmlns:md="_"></md:EntityDescriptor>'
```

Expected:

```
<md:EntityDescriptor xmlns:md="_"></md:EntityDescriptor>
```

Answer (score 1):

(Responding to the [xmlstarlet](/questions/tagged/xmlstarlet) tag.)

They're not attribute nodes but namespace nodes so they exist on the
`namespace` [axis](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116#axes), not the `attribute` axis.

For the input file you posted, converting to [PYX](https://fossies.org/linux/xmlstarlet/doc/xmlstarlet-ug.html#idm47077139550832)
format during editing will produce the desired output (with a non-closed
empty root element):

```shell
$ xmlstarlet pyx file.xml | grep -v '^Axmlns urn:_' | xmlstarlet depyx
<md:EntityDescriptor xmlns:md="_"></md:EntityDescriptor>
```

In case input is part of a larger file make sure that no elements
exist in the default namespace -- which is
[bound](https://fossies.org/linux/xmlstarlet/doc/xmlstarlet-ug.html#idm47077139523728)
to the `_` (underscore) prefix since it's declared in the root element:

```sh
xmlstarlet select -Q -t -c '(//_:*)[1]' file.xml
if test "$?" -eq 1; then
  xmlstarlet pyx file.xml | grep -v '^Axmlns urn:_' | xmlstarlet depyx
fi
```

where [`select -Q`](https://fossies.org/linux/xmlstarlet/doc/xmlstarlet-ug.html#idm47077139652416) returns 1 if none was found.
Note that `grep` may limit line length, cf. `getconf LINE_MAX`.

**Beware** of a number of issues with  `pyx / depyx`, e.g.
bug referencing *external entities*,
XML special characters inside comments output as character entity references,
`depyx` outputs non-collapsed empty elements.
(Alternative: [`xml2 / 2xml`](https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/xml2))

---

If `xmlstarlet` had been finished,

```sh
xmlstarlet edit --omit-decl --pf -d '//namespace::*[name()=""]' file.xml
```

should do what you're asking but that'll get you no more than a
`FIXME: can't delete namespace nodes` error.

And in this case `xmlstarlet format`'s `-N (--nsclean)` option doesn't
remove redundant namespace declarations.